# Google App Engine - Deleted Entity is not deleted

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to delete an entity in google datastore

```
String keyValue = "someValue";
Key tweetKey = KeyFactory.createKey("tweetKey", keyValue);
Entity someEntity = new Entity(tweetKey);

Entity getEntity = datastore.get(tweetKey);
datastore.delete(tweetKey);
getEntity = datastore.get(tweetKey);
if(getEntity != null)
{
   //This happens
   System.out.println("Something wrong");
}
```

The entity are not deleted, and it something wrong as the output

Edit 1: I didn't copy and paste from the original code, because there are a lot of other logic in between getting and using values from the entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deleting a different key than the one you are checking.

You are deleting the `tweetKey` and checking the `tweetkey` (notice the capital `K` in the first one). If this snippet is a copy paste from your original then that's the mistake.

Comment: Solution: Checking the wrong key, and some wrong logic, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have a transaction active and if you do commit it.